# Can't change color of KML Polygon, Style tag shows as invalid

Tags: html, google-maps, colors, kml

I have a KML file I'm using google sites to host. The link is working in my code, because I can see the map as an overlay. But when I put any style in the KML, the page seem to ignore it. I tried to change it to yellow, but I only get the default blue. The KML has polygons with inner and outer boundaries. The code is being views in my editor (Coda 2). The map shows, and it's in the right place, but it's not the right color. Is there a way for me to change the color? see code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Coverage Map</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 80%;
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: chicago,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'https://sites.google.com/site/dmckmls/home/kml/Sprint.kml'
  });
  ctaLayer.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The KMLLayers will be cached b google, you must wait a couple of minutes or use a different filename to see the changes.

Comment: Also see https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#fill

Comment: I read the fill documentation. Thanks Dr. Molle. No help. I was using the same code from that documentation in a previous version of the code and still no dice. I waited a few minutes, and even used a different file name but it still didn't change color. Thank you for the suggestions. Any other ideas?

Comment: Your [KML displayed by the Google Maps Javascript API v3 KmlLayer](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=https://sites.google.com/site/dmckmls/home/kml/Sprint.kml).  What do you expect it to look like?

Comment: The map is correct but I'm trying to change it to a different color. It's shows as blue but I set the polystyle fill to yellow (KML compatible). No matter what color I set, it always shows as blue.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the name of the file. I read about that somewhere as well for the change. That's rather annoying on google's parts. Such a powerful tool and they can't update the file because they have to cache it for performance sake. Thanks everyone for the help.